# Cassandra and wide row disk size estimate?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql, diskspace

I am trying to estimate the amount of space required for each column in a Cassandra wide row, but the numbers that I get are wildly conflicting.

I have a pretty standard wide row table to store some time series data:

```
CREATE TABLE raw_data (
   id uuid,
   time timestamp,
   data list<float>,
   PRIMARY KEY (id, time)
);
```

In my case, I store 20 floats in the data list.

Datastax [provides](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/architecture/architecturePlanningUserData_t.html) some formulas for estimating user data size.

```
regular_total_column_size = column_name_size + column_value_size + 15
row_size = key_size + 23
primary_key_index = number_of_rows * ( 32 + average_key_size )
```

For this table, we get the following values:

```
regular_total_column_size = 8 + 80 + 15 = 103 bytes
row_size = 16 + 23 = 39 bytes
primary_key_index = 276 * ( 32 + 16 ) = 13248 bytes
```

I'm mostly interested in how the row grows, so the 103 bytes per column is of interest. I counted all the samples in my database and ended up with 29,241,289 unique samples. Multiplying it out I get an estimated `raw_data` table size of 3GB.

In reality, I have 4GB of *compressed* data as measured by `nodetool cfstats` right after compaction. It reports a compression ratio of 0.117. It averages out to 137 bytes per sample, on disk, after compression. That seems very high, considering:

- only 88 bytes of that is user data
- It's 34 bytes more per sample
- This is after deflate compression.

So, my question is: **how do I accurately forecast how much disk space Cassandra wide rows consume, and how can I minimize the total disk space?**

I'm running a single node with no replication for these tests.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to compaction strategies. With size tiered compaction, the SSTables will build up to double the required space during compaction. For levelled compaction, around 10% extra space will be needed. Depending on compaction strategy, you need to take into account the additional disk spaced used.